# Connecting to a TCP port using Scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, tcp, scapy

I've been playing around with scapy and I have a small question...
Let's say I have a socket open on a server, say at port 80 at the IP address 1.2.3.4, and say it is listening for and recording any connections.
Now, I want to connect to this port from my client (say 2.3.4.5) using scapy, so I have to initiate a three-way handshake, which I've been trying to execute using the following code:

```
ip=IP(src="2.3.4.5", dst="1.2.3.4")
TCP_SYN=TCP(sport=1500, dport=80, flags="S", seq=100)
TCP_SYNACK=sr1(ip/TCP_SYN)

my_ack = TCP_SYNACK.seq + 1
TCP_ACK=TCP(sport=1500, dport=80, flags="A", seq=101, ack=my_ack)
send(TCP_ACK/ip)

my_payload="space for rent!"
TCP_PUSH=TCP(sport=1500, dport=80, flags="PA", seq=102, ack=my_ack)
sendp(ip/TCP_PUSH/my_payload)
```

But I never get a response from the server; the console just prints "Finished to send 1 packets." and then prints a stream of dots. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) Looks like "send" and "sendp" can't receive the answer.

2) So you can try this:

```
ip=IP(src="2.3.4.5", dst="1.2.3.4")
TCP_SYN=TCP(sport=1500, dport=80, flags="S", seq=100)
TCP_SYNACK=sr1(ip/TCP_SYN)

print(TCP_SYNACK)
print(TCP_SYNACK.show())
```

One of this print should show you the response from the server.

3) You can try to change your "send" and "sendp" to "sr" or "sr1", and then print result:

```
my_ack = TCP_SYNACK.seq + 1
TCP_ACK=TCP(sport=1500, dport=80, flags="A", seq=101, ack=my_ack)
answ, un_answ = sr(TCP_ACK/ip)

print(answ)
print(answ.summary())
print(answ.show())
```

I'm not sure that this will work, never used the scapy before, so wait for your answer.